# SOAP Response not unserialized correctly in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, soap, flex4, wsdl

I am seeing certain nodes of my SOAP response disappearing in Flex 4.  I am using an `<mx:WebService>` that is written using PHP/nusoap and 99% of the responses are unserialized correctly in Flex.  For some reason this snippet is causing problems:

RAW XML:

```
<data xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:reportData[1]">
  <item xsi:type="tns:reportData">
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Tue.  8 Mar. 2011</name>
    <year xsi:type="xsd:int">2011</year>
    <month xsi:type="xsd:int">3</month>
    <day xsi:type="xsd:int">8</day>
    <counts xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:double[3]">
      <item xsi:type="xsd:double">26</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:double">11</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:double">11</item>
    </counts>
  </item>
</data>
```

The only element to show in the Flex ProxyObject is "name".  All other values are simply ignored.

The WSDL defines reportData as:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="reportData">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="url" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:int"/>
   <xsd:element name="month" type="xsd:int"/>
   <xsd:element name="day" type="xsd:int"/>
   <xsd:element name="hour" type="xsd:int"/>
   <xsd:element name="counts" type="tns:reportCountList"/>
   <xsd:element name="breakdown_total" type="tns:reportCountList"/>
   <xsd:element name="breakdown" type="tns:reportDataList"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

Any ideas why this XML will not unserialize correctly?

Comment: Perhaps because the `url` node is missing? Just a guess. My XML is rusty.

Comment: Ahh...I think you may be right there.  According to http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#element-all minOccurs defaults to 1 meaning it needs to be explicitly set to minOccurs=0 in the WSDL.  Let me try this.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if that turns out to be it and I'll add it as an official answer so you can accept it in case others run into a similar issue.

Comment: Sure enough...that worked.  I changed the WSDL to explicitly define those optional elements as minOccurs="0" and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above:

> According to w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#element-all minOccurs defaults to 1 meaning it needs to be explicitly set to minOccurs=0 in the WSDL.

The above SOAP response was missing the required `url` element. Changing the WSDL to explicitly define the `url` element as optional `minOccurs="0"` fixes the issue.